# How to remove facebook news add from my browser

Tags: google-chrome, facebook, unwanted-application

Hi i'm getting this advert while surfing the internet. It's very iritating please help me

`http://facebook.com-important-finance-news.ninja/?z9ps5pq2l3`

Comment: It seems your computer is infected.

Comment: Please tell me what to do

Comment: http://superuser.com/questions/100360/how-can-i-remove-malicious-spyware-malware-viruses-or-rootkits-from-my-pc

Comment: I am debating if that link should even be live.  It is obvious that its not a Facebook website.

Comment: The link is definitely one impersonating Facebook and is potentially malicious so it needs to be made obvious what it is, not hidden. I've marked it as a duplicate for now, so please take the time to read the duplicate question and if you are stuck with any of the points raised there or you have additional information to provide then let us know or edit your question to tell us exactly what you have tried.

Answer (score 0):

The URL **isn't Facebook**, and if you click on anything or submit personal data it could have serious consequences. I suggest you edit your post to remove the URL in case others are fooled by it.

Go to http://malwarebytes.org and get the free scanner. (note that you will be persuaded to buy the premium version but free is adequate) Do a full scan of your HD. Usually this will identify the Trojan.

If you are at all unsure of having removed the infection, then a data backup, full disk erase and OS reload would be wise, especially if you use the computer for banking or the like. You might also want to change your banking password in case it's been uploaded.